# Listener for the System.out.* into the TextArea

Tags: java, javafx, javafx-2, output, observable

I've read and implemented Observable/Observer Design Pattern. But somehow it does not work. And I Can't find the solution. Maybe I'm passing something. I would be happy and thankfull for Your advice. Codes are below:

Observable:

```
import java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream;
import java.util.Observable;

public class ObservableOfOutput extends Observable {

    private ByteArrayOutputStream baos;

    public ObservableOfOutput(ByteArrayOutputStream baos) {
        synchronized (this) {
            this.baos = baos;
        }
        setChanged();
        notifyObservers();
    }

    public synchronized ByteArrayOutputStream getBaos() {
        return this.baos;
    }
}
```

Observer:

```
import java.util.Observable;
import java.util.Observer;

import javafx.scene.control.TextArea;

public class ObserverOfOutput implements Observer {
    private TextArea ta;

    public ObserverOfOutput(TextArea ta) {
        super();
        this.ta = ta;
    }

    public void observe(Observable o) {
        o.addObserver(this);
    }
    @Override
    public void update(Observable o, Object arg) {
        ObserverOfOutput.this.ta.setText(((ObservableOfOutput) o).getBaos().toString());
    }
}
```

Class that uses them:

```
// do something usefull

// Change outputs into the custom output stream
ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
System.setOut(new PrintStream(baos));
System.setErr(new PrintStream(baos));
ObservableOfOutput observableBAOS = new ObservableOfOutput(baos);

// text area to print results
TextArea console = new TextArea();
ObserverOfOutput observerTA = new ObserverOfOutput(console);
observerTA.observe(observableBAOS);

// show console
showCustomConsole(console); // shows new window with this TextArea

System.out.println("Starting the tool using following parameters:\n");
System.out.println("Blabla");
System.out.println("Blablabla2");
System.out.println("Tool finished its work.");
```

Just forwarding the last output to the TextArea is easy with console.setText(baos.toString()) writing it at the end. But it is not what I need. I need this listener to make a real-time output on the TextArea. The tool runs for a long time and throws strings using System.out/err.println. I want to catch them when they are thrown and put them in to the TextArea.

Thanks in Advance. :-)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27800326/hook-into-system-out-println-and-modify

Comment: @KevinKal - Thanks, but in my App, I use threads, that is why, can not catch output like Processes :-(

Comment: @trashgod - Thank You too, but this is not, what I want.

Comment: Does not help either :-(
But thanks for Your try. :-)