# Suppress console output - SimpleOpenNI Processing

Tags: console, output, processing, simple-openni

I'm wondering if there is a way to suppress console output from a single library in processing? Specifically, I am using SimpleOpenNI and it constantly outputs stuff like the below many times a second:

> [Info] [VTRgbPacketProcessor] avg. time: 22.8676ms -> ~43.73Hz [Info]
>   [DepthPacketStreamParser] 1 packets were lost [Info]
>   [OpenGLDepthPacketProcessor] avg. time: 5.9517ms -> ~168.019Hz

The library is working fine but the output is a bit annoying as I'm trying to use the console to test stuff.

Anyone know a way to suppress output from a specific library? I've looked through the SimpleOpenNI docs and cant find anything that helps.

Cheers

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You generally have three options:

**Option 1:** Hopefully the library provides a way to disable console output. Look for something like `setLogLevel()` or `suppressWarnings()`.

**Option 2:** If the library is open source, you could just modify it yourself to get rid of the print statements.

**Option 3:** You could also modify the `System.out` variable to point to your own custom class that filters messages you don't care about.

Comment: Great thanks! Opt 1 & 2 were unavailable but I found [this thread that helped](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27800326/hook-into-system-out-println-and-modify) write a new class

Comment: @JordanE yep, that's pretty much exactly what I had in mind. Glad you got it figured out.